Function to split string and extract first result - list index out of range
I have a df with a column of values in the following format:
['Action', 'Adventure', 'Science Fiction']
I am trying to write a function to extract the first result (i.e. 'Action') and even though I expect it's quite basic I am going around in circles.
def genresplit(x):
    return str.split("''")[1]

This returns the following:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[141], line 1
----> 1 genresplit(['Action', 'Adventure', 'Science Fiction'])

Cell In[140], line 2, in genresplit(x)
      1 def genresplit(x):
----> 2     return str.split("''")[1]

IndexError: list index out of range

I assume this is missing the whole string and looking for something after it that is not there but how should I be specifying the first answer that I want?

What do you expect str.split("''") will do, and why?

did you mean x.split()?

You already supply a list, so why are you trying to split it? Just take the first element? The first element would be [0], not [1]. You pass the value to a parameter named x, but never use it. You try to split on two single-quote characters, but there are no occurences of two single-quote characters, any where.

What is the data type of the column? If it is already a list you can get the values easily using a function such as apply. If it is a string, then you can convert the data type for each cell and get the list out of that string and select the first element

str.split should be applied on a string (str), like this
print("a-b-c".split("-"))  # ['a', 'b', 'c']


What you have is a list, if you want the first element, use the index, there is no split notion for a list
def genresplit(x):
    return x[0]

